# Why does libparted detect partitions with negative labels?

Tags: c++, linux, disk-partitioning, parted

Maybe I'm not using the right keywords for my Google searches. In that case, please point me in the right direction.

I'm using libparted to detect connected mass-storage media and partitions on my device.
One thing I've noticed, is that devices which Linux detects as SATA/SCSI also seem to have a partition with a negative partition number, e.g. `/dev/sda-1`

When I look for the files in the filesystem (`/proc/`) for example, I cannot see these partitions. Even calling `parted` (`print all`) doesn't display these results. However, using multiple versions of libparted across multiple devices and even toolchains gives me the same results.

For now I've just output a warning message stating that an erroneous partition has been found, but maybe I'm just misinterpreting something?
The partitions have no size, no mount point, just the name - they do show up multiple times per device.

So far, these messages have turned up:

```
[2022-10-17 14:13:42.597] [warning] Found erroneous partiton label /dev/sda-1 // hard disk
[2022-10-17 14:13:42.597] [warning] Found erroneous partition label /dev/sda-1
[2022-10-17 14:13:42.684] [warning] Found erroneous partition label /dev/sdb-1 // flash drive
[2022-10-17 14:13:42.684] [warning] Found erroneous partition label /dev/sdb-1
[2022-10-17 14:13:42.685] [warning] Found erroneous partition label /dev/sdb-1
[2022-10-17 14:13:42.708] [warning] Found erroneous partition label /dev/sdc-1 // also flash drive
[2022-10-17 14:13:42.708] [warning] Found erroneous partition label /dev/sdc-1
[2022-10-17 14:13:42.720] [warning] Found erroneous partition label /dev/sdd-1 // another flash drive
[2022-10-17 14:13:42.721] [warning] Found erroneous partition label /dev/sdd-1
[2022-10-17 14:13:42.721] [warning] Found erroneous partition label /dev/sdd-1
```

The rest of the data looks okay: (excerpt)

```json
"DevicePath": "/dev/sda2",
"DeviceType": "Partition",
"FreeSpace": 531341312,
"HasPartitions": false,
"MountPath": "/boot/efi",
"PartitionList": null,
"TotalCapacity": 536834048,
"UsedSpace": 5492736
```

The complete information (as given by parted):

```
Model: VMware, VMware Virtual S (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 215GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags:

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name  Flags
 1      1049kB  2097kB  1049kB                     bios_grub
 2      2097kB  540MB   538MB   fat32              boot, esp
 3      540MB   215GB   214GB                      lvm
```

Does the negative partition number have a specific meaning, or is it something I can safely ignore without missing on any information?

*tag libparted doesn't exist. If someone w/ enough rep wants to create one, please feel free. This issue doesn't apply to parted.*

Comment: Can you check the major/minor number of the device against the kernel doc? https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/Documentation/admin-guide/devices.txt

Comment: So far it all checks out